# pgadmin, postgres and gogole cloud connection time out

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, pgadmin-4

I followed [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-postgres).

I managed to set up everything and do exactly as it was mentioned in the tutorial.

But when I tried to connect to it using PGADMIN 4, i get connection time and out and I was never able to fix it.

then I found [this link](https://rimina.wordpress.com/2016/03/11/databases-at-first-sight-postgresql/), which has the following command:

```
sudo -i -u postgres
psql
\conninfo
```

then I cans see the following message:

```
You are connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres" via socket in "/var/run/postgresql" at port "5432".
```

So I dont understand what is wrong now and when I type:
`sudo nano ../../etc/postgresql/9.3/main/pg_hba.conf`
to see the content of the file and I put my password, its not being accepted.

Then I restart everything by closing the window and open it again, then I can check out the file:

```
# If you change this first entry you will need to make sure that the
# database superuser can access the database using some other method.
# Noninteractive access to all databases is required during automatic
# maintenance (custom daily cronjobs, replication, and similar tasks).
# 
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
# IPv4 remote connections for the tutorial:
#host     all             all             127.0.0.1/32           md5
#host     all             all             35.196.55.208/32       md5
host     all             all             all                     md5
```

The last 4 lines I've added to fix the problem, but nothing yet.

What am I doing wrong? I'm looking at many tutorials, and also several pages from Stack Overflow but still nothing!

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided permission to connect remotely.

In the given tutorial, `Connecting remotely` section it is clearly mentioned that you need to provide your IP address in the `pg_hba.conf` file.

> Replace [YOUR_IPV4_ADDRESS] with the address of your local computer.
>
> Also, In the Instances page in the Google Cloud Platform Console, click the
>   instance to open its Overview page. Select the Authorization tab.
>   Under Authorized networks, click Add network and enter the IP address
>   of the client machine where your client is installed. Click Done, then
>   click Save at the bottom of your page to save your changes. Connect to
>   your instance, either with SSL or without SSL.

Provide your IP address in the `pg_hba.conf` file, Restart Postgres service and try again.

Comment: 127.0.0.1/32 this ip which is also in that file!

Comment: i think the problem might be with i address I am not sure if im using the correct one or not!

Comment: `127.0.0.1/32` is for localhost (ie pgadmin & postgres installed on the same machine) connection, you have to provide your IP address in order to connect it remotely.  If you are confirmable to access your machine from everywhere then you can try adding  `host     all             all             0.0.0.0/0           md5` though I would not suggest that for security reasons.

Comment: I made this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789411/connecting-to-a-postgres-db-in-google-cloud-with-my-pc I think I explained much better!

Comment: I made a remote connection with the IPV4 address/32. I removed the last 3 lines and I made just 1 line!